# Align text in footer table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, header-footer, alignment, scrlttr2

How to edit the first column tabular in the footer so the text of the marked rows is aligned?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, version=last, fromalign=left, backaddress=true, foldmarks=on, fromphone=off, fromemail=off, parskip=half, firsthead=false]{scrlttr2} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{blindtext}
            
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}   

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}  % Signatur wird bündig gesetzt


\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% Absender
% 
\newcommand{\mVorname}{stupid company GmbH} 
\newcommand{\mNachname}{\& Co. KG} 
\newcommand{\mStrasse}{Somestreet. 1} 
\newcommand{\mStadt}{Somecity} 
\newcommand{\mPLZ}{22223} 
\setkomavar{date}{} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{\mVorname{}~\mNachname{}}               % Name 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\mStrasse{}\\{}\mPLZ{}~\mStadt{}}    % Adresse
\setkomavar{frombank}{SomeBank\\ 
            IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\BIC: AAAAAAAAAAA}

\setkomavar{location}{\raggedright 
Versandanschrift:\\
\vfill
Some Guy   \\
23423 Blablubbing       \\ 
Blabistan               \\
Telefon
} 

\makeatletter
\@setplength{locvpos}{4.8cm}
\@setplength{locwidth}{7.5cm}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{250mm}
\makeatother

\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
\showfields{address}% show the address box



% header and footer first page:
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{% changed ->
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}%
  \parbox{\useplength{firstfootwidth}}{%
      \rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}\\
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}  
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Geschäftsinformation:}}\\ 
          persönlich haftende Gesellschafterin:\\ 
          stupid company Verwaltungs-GmbH\\
          Sitz Somecity \\
          Amtsgericht Somecity, HBR 111111 \\
          Handelsregister: Somecity HRA222222 \\
          USt-IdNr.: DE 000000000 \\
          WEEE-Nr.:  DE 00000000 \\
          Geschäftsführer: Some Guy
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{\usekomavar*{frombank}:}} \smallskip \\
          \usekomavar{frombank} 
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{} \smallskip \\ 
          Someotherbank \\
          IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\
          BIC: BBBBBBBBBBB
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
  }%
}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  hoffset=\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-.5\useplength{firstfootwidth}\relax,
  width=\useplength{firstfootwidth},
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putUL{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}
]{likefirstpage.foot}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{likefirstpage.foot}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead*{\pagemark}

\begin{document} 

%recipient  
\begin{letter}{%    
Max Musterkunde \\
Teststraße 2    \\
55555 Teststadt \\
Schweiz         \\ 
     }
    

% 
%\setkomavar{title}{Titel} 
\setkomavar{subject}{BETREFF} 
% 
\opening{}
%

    



%\Blindtext


\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add the very beginning, i.e. the documentclass you are using? Thanks

Comment: Since "text of the marked rows is aligned"  is an ambiguous description, would you mind adding a sketch of the expected output? Do you want all 4 lines to be aligned with respect to each other or just the two part that share the same color? DO you want the texts to be right of left aligned...?

Comment: Another trick is to use \makebox or \hbox to ... for a given width.  `\makebox[3cm]{Amtsgericht Somecity, HBR\hfill 111111}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

[image]

is the desired output, you may want to use a table containing two columns and some more `\multicolumn` commands instead of a table that contains just a single column:

```
% header and footer first page:
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{% changed ->
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}%
  \parbox{\useplength{firstfootwidth}}{%
      \rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}\\
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\,}r@{}}  
          \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Geschäftsinformation:}}\\ 
          \multicolumn{2}{l}{persönlich haftende Gesellschafterin:}\\ 
          \multicolumn{2}{l}{stupid company Verwaltungs-GmbH}\\
          \multicolumn{2}{l}{Sitz Somecity} \\
          Amtsgericht Somecity,& HBR 111111 \\
          Handelsregister: Somecity &HRA222222 \\
          USt-IdNr.:& DE 000000000 \\
          WEEE-Nr.: & DE 00000000 \\
          \multicolumn{2}{l}{Geschäftsführer: Some Guy}
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{\usekomavar*{frombank}:}} \smallskip \\
          \usekomavar{frombank} 
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{} \smallskip \\ 
          Someotherbank \\
          IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\
          BIC: BBBBBBBBBBB
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
  }%
}
```

---

If you're on the other hand interested in

[image]

nested tabulars may come in handy:

```
% header and footer first page:
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{% changed ->
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}%
  \parbox{\useplength{firstfootwidth}}{%
      \rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}\\
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}  
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Geschäftsinformation:}}\\ 
          persönlich haftende Gesellschafterin:\\ 
          stupid company Verwaltungs-GmbH\\
          Sitz Somecity \\
          \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\;}l@{}}Amtsgericht Somecity,& HBR 111111 \\
          Handelsregister: Somecity &HRA222222 \end{tabular}\\
          \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\;}l@{}}USt-IdNr.:& DE 000000000 \\
          WEEE-Nr.: & DE 00000000 \end{tabular}\\
          Geschäftsführer: Some Guy
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{\usekomavar*{frombank}:}} \smallskip \\
          \usekomavar{frombank} 
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{} \smallskip \\ 
          Someotherbank \\
          IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\
          BIC: BBBBBBBBBBB
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
  }%
}
```

Comment: thx the second one is that what I was going for!